# zsh parameter expansion with asterisk as variable does not work

Tags: zsh

[image]

I am trying to remove a file extension using parameter expansion. e.g. given a filename of 123.sh, return 123.

If I store the pattern, ".*" in a variable, it does not work —${filename%$suffix} does not work.

If I specify the pattern literally, it does — ${filename%.*}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expansion `${filename%$suffix}`, the value of `$suffix` is substituted *literally*. To have it be substitute as a *pattern* instead, you will need to use [glob substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion): `${filename%$~suffix}`

However, none of this is necessary for what you're trying to do. To remove the extension from a filename, you can simply use the `r` [modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-modifiers):

```sh
❯ filename="123.sh"
❯ print $filename:r
123
```